# current_user_can on WordPress 3.1.1

Tags: fatal-error

I just upgraded to WordPress 3.1.1 and suddenly I'm getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /home/arisehub/arisehub.org/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1028`

I've narrowed it down to my usage of "current_user_can"

Example:

`if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) { add_action('admin_init','customize_page_meta_boxes');  }`

Removing that reference to current_user_can removes the errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling the function too early. The `functions.php` is included before `current_user_can()` is defined. **Never** do anything before the hook `'after_setup_theme'`:

### Example for the functions.php

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( 'WPSE_14041_Base', 'setup' ) );

class WPSE_14041_Base
{
    public static function setup()
    {
        ! isset ( $GLOBALS['content_width'] ) and $GLOBALS['content_width'] = 480;

        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        add_theme_support( 'menus' );

        add_editor_style();

        add_custom_background();

        // You may use current_user_can() here. And more. :)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the 'plugins_loaded' action is fired almost immediately after the pluggable.php file is loaded, this would be the optimal action to hook.

Comment: add_action isn't defined until after functions.php is included! Where should this code be placed? @toscho

Comment: @bozdoz `add_action()` exists already at the very bottom of the `wp-config.php`. That's very early even before the mu-plugins are loaded.