# Having a lot of difficulty getting add_editor_style() to load into source code

Tags: wysiwyg, add-editor-style

I have tried many different things to get `add_editor_style()` to load into the source code on my site without any luck. I would like to use `editor-style.css` to customize CSS properties for my WordPress WYSIWYG. However, I am unable to get it working. Even when I look in Chrome Inspector's Resources tab and scroll down to "Stylesheets" I don't see any listing of `editor-style.css`

Here's what I tried so far:

1. Placed `editor-style.css` in the root of my theme directory
2. `<?php add_editor_style(); ?>` is placed in my `functions.php` file for my theme (I've even moved around this function call to editor style in my `functions.php` to see if that would do the trick … no luck.
3. All of my CSS and JavaScripts are registered and enqueued in my functions.php file

Is there some type of override going on that I am not aware of?

Comment: On which action do you call `add_editor_style()`?

Comment: I'm calling it directly within my theme as is. Is that incorrect?

Comment: You should always [wait until `after_setup_theme`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14042/73). Does that work?

Comment: It doesn't...I activated the TwentyEleven theme and I don't even see editor-style.css getting loaded into the source here either. Am I missing something amount the way this works? I see editor-style.css in TwentyEleven's theme root...

Comment: The editor style is applied to the iframe in TinyMCE’s visual editor only. Make sure to inspect exactly that. Try to set a red background for `.mceContentBody` to see immediately if the CSS is used.

Comment: Therefore I shouldn't see editor-style.css loaded into Chrome Inspector's (or Firebug's) resources view? Are these styles being injected into my theme's main stylesheet?

Comment: In Opera, you can see it in the resources, don’t know about other browsers. And no, it is not merged with the main stylesheet.

Comment: @fluxia thanks for identifying `.mceContentBody`.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't call `add_editor_style()` directly in your `functions.php` file. Instead, you should wait until the plugins and themes have been loaded:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_editor_style' );
```

If you already have a function hooked to `after_setup_theme`, you can call `add_editor_style()` inside there instead.

---

You then need create a file called `editor-style.css` and place it in your theme direcrory. You must not place it in a subfolder; otherwise it will not be found. Try using this code in `editor-style.css`, just to see if it is working:

```
body#tinymce.wp-editor { 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    margin:10px; 
}

body#tinymce.wp-editor a {
    color: #ffa500;
}
```

If the editor appears in a different font with orange links, then it works!

---

Contuary to what you are assuming, `editor-style.css` will **not** show up under the "Stylesheets" section of Chrome's developer tools. This is because the visual editor is loaded in an `<iframe>` element; essentially it is on another webpage that is embedded into the new post page. On this external page is where the `editor-style.css` stylesheet is loaded.

If you *really* want to check is `editor-style.css` is loaded, you can right-click on the visual editor body and choose **Inspect Element** from the context menu. Just above the line that is highlighted, you should see a `<link>` element pointing to your `editor-style.css` file.

[image: Screenshot of using Chrome Developer Tools on my own dev site]

---

You should also read the [Codex page for `add_editor_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style).

Comment: I was calling add_editor_style through `admin_init`. Why is this different from `after_setup_theme`?

Isn't `admin_init` only going to fire when an admin page is loaded, whereas `after_setup_theme`... on every page load?

Answer (score 0):

Had difficulty until finding `parent theme was calling add_editor_style()`

The Twenty Fourteen should wrap this so it's possible dequeueing the call with `remove_action`, not editing the parent `functions.php`

Answer (score -1):

**Correct Answer**: Put `add_editor_style('editor-style.css');` in a function hooked to `after_setup_theme` action hook. Pass the name of file you want to use for editor  CSS as the argument, or skip the argument if you want the name to be 'editor-style.css' as it's optional.

**Wrong Answer**: The optional parameter doesn't seem to be optional. This works for me:

```
add_editor_style('editor-style.css');
```

And yep, it's okay to call it directly in your theme's functions.php.

Comment: The parameter *is* actually optional. WordPress will include the `editor-style.css` stylesheet just fine if no parameter is passed. Also: you should *always* put functional code inside callbacks hooked into an appropriate action hook in `functions.php`.