# How do I disable dashboard update notifications for subscribers?

Tags: dashboard, updates

For registered users to my blog, if they click on the dashboard, they get an alert suggesting that they tell the site administrator (me) that the new version of WordPress is available.

All I want is to hide dashboard alerts from the subscribers.  Where can I find the code to change this?

I found a site [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/making-dashboard-alerts) that suggests that I'm looking for the code:

```
add_action('admin_head','addDashboardAlert');
```

But I don't know where to look for it.

### UPDATE

I found some more relevant code to make the alerts conditional on user role, [here](http://wplifeguard.com/how-to-add-custom-alerts-to-a-wordpress-dashboard/):

```
if (!current_user_can('delete_posts')) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can include some custom css in your functions.php that hides the update_nag (notifications) element dependent on user capability:

```
add_action('admin_head','admin_css');
function admin_css()
{
if(!current_user_can('administrator'))//not and admin
{
    echo '<style>';
        echo '.update_nag{display:none}';
        echo '</style>';
    }
}
```

Comment: add_action and current_user_can won't work in functions.php; however, just hiding the elements with CSS seems to be the best way to do it so far. +1

Comment: add_action and current_user_can does work in your theme's functions.php - I have used this exact code in over 30 sites with not a drama?

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free to share my question - unresolved after many months, I've nearly lost all my hair over it!

Comment: This is not really a good answer at all.

Answer (score 9):

*Updating* this answer the original code below will remove the nag screen but it will ping the server for updates on every load, thanks to @ El Yobo, see update below.

This will disable the core updates and the nag screen to everyone but superadmins.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_core_updates' );
function remove_core_updates()
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'update_core' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );" ), 2 );
    add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', '__return_null' );
    add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', '__return_null' ); 
}
```

To disable all plugin notifications;

```
remove_action( 'load-update-core.php', 'wp_update_plugins' );
add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_plugins', '__return_null' );
```

To remove a specific plugin you can try this but it is not 100% going to work depending on the plugin;

```
function ya_remove_plugin_update($value) {
     $plugin_relative_path = "plugin_relative_path"; // change this to your plugin
     unset( $value->response[ $plugin_relative_path ] );
     return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'ya_remove_plugin_update' );
```

---

**Updated**

This disable updates completely (I cannot get it to work based on user roles) *AND* stop pinging for updates (It will throw a PHP warning not sure how to fix this without altering core).

```
function remove_core_updates(){

        global $wp_version;
        return (object) array(
            'last_checked' => time(),
            'version_checked' => $wp_version,
            );
}
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_core', 'remove_core_updates');
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_plugins', 'remove_core_updates');
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_themes', 'remove_core_updates');
```

Comment: Thanks @Wyck.  Where would I put this info?  Into wp-config?

Comment: No these functions would go in your theme's functions.php or a plugin.

Comment: At the bottom? Top? Doesn't matter? @Wyck

Comment: Not working in functions.php, says the functions are undefined: current_user_can

Comment: That function will only work on WordPress 3.0 and above and must be called after functions.php loads, see here, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14041/current-user-can-on-wordpress-3-1-1

Comment: that's not working either.  It says add_action isn't defined.

Comment: understood.  I'll have to see if I can get your answer to work.

Comment: Sorry I tested my answer and It was not 100% correct, I have updated it.

Comment: Why we don't use `__return_null` for the 3rd filter `pre_site_transient_update_core`? It's shorter ;)

Comment: Ya copy/paste typo I did use it in the second example, fixed:)

Comment: Wyck, returning null to the filter forces WP to continuously check for updates because it can't tell when the last check run.  See my [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821419/wordpress-plugin-notifications/14935077) answer for a simple solution which works better.

Comment: Did not know that, I'll look into it if that is the case and change my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't manage to work with those scripts above so I researched a bit more and found this:

```
//Remove update notifications from sub-users
add_action('admin_head','admin_css');
function admin_css()
{
    // Choose the correct role where you need to block update nag
    if( current_user_can('YOUR_SELECTED_ROLE')) {
        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', '__return_null' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deriving from @wyck's answer, all update notices and PHP warnings are now hidden using the script below. Just place this in your `functions.php`

```
function remove_core_updates() {
  global $wp_version;
  return (object) array(
    'last_checked' => time(),
    'version_checked' => $wp_version,
  );
}
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_core', 'remove_core_updates');
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_plugins', 'remove_core_updates');
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_themes', 'remove_core_updates');


function remove_menu() {
  global $submenu;
  if (isset($submenu['index.php'][10]))
    unset($submenu['index.php'][10]); // Removes 'Updates'.
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menu');
```