# Slow WP loading due to persistent version check, how to disable?

Tags: wp-admin, updates

Recently I noticed WP is running very slow, esp. with editor/admin login , checking "site Health",  with help of [Query-monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/)I found out critical issue that WP cannot reach wordPress.org:

*Your site is unable to reach WordPress.org at 198.143.164.251, and returned the error: cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10002 milliseconds*

In fact this is correct, because my WP is installed/configured for local LAN access. But then the forceful access to external website has made WP slow and lame.

I have checked [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102554/prevent-disable-automatic-update-check) and add 2 lines in my wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
```

But the slow loading didn't solve, while *wp-include/update.php* still demands to check *https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/* and persistent, thus makes WP lame.

**How to correctly disable WP version check/persistent external access?**

---

PS: currently I awkwardly commented out the line `/* $response = wp_remote_post( $url, $options );*/` , which temporarily solve the slow loading issue. (<1s), but not a downright solution.

Comment: Could you set an entry in `/etc/hosts` or your local DNS to point api.wordpress.com to `127.0.0.1`, and just return 404 from that address? That looks like it might short-circuit the update check.

Comment: @PatJ : thanks. just tried but not effective. It is strange `auto_update` disabled but still `version_check` active. where's the setting for it? PS: it makes also no sense, because Synology has its own package center for update(delayed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent/Disable Automatic Update Check](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102554/prevent-disable-automatic-update-check)

Comment: @kraftner:thanks! as you saw my post has referred to that thread and implemented the given solution, yet not solved the issue of persistent  version_check.

Comment: Sorry, missed the reference. Did you also look at the other answers? I think this might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/320194/47733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around, found [plugin: Disable Wordpress Updates](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/disable-wordpress-updates/) is one of the effective & easy solutions, which also included [disable version check](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/suggest-to-block-also-https-api-wordpress-org-core-version-check/) to contact https://api.wordpress.com/. PS: really hope WP could include this option for users as well.

If there any insightful and explanatory solution, I still prefer to hear, please suggest.
(PS: seems WP@SE is bit non-popular/active, let's wait some days to close)