# How to use the 'Quick edit' option only for Admin and Editor in 'All posts' on the Dashboard?

Tags: dashboard

I have a multi author blog. I want to use the 'Quick edit' option only for Admin and Editor on Dashboard not for Author or other Users. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional depending on capability.  Admin's and Editors can both moderate comments so we can use the `moderate_comments` capability.  If a user cannot moderate comments, then remove the quick edit link.

Then we can filter `post_row_actions` to remove the quick edit link.

```
function remove_quick_edit(){

    function unset_quick_edit( $actions ) {
        unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
            return $actions;
    }

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'moderate_comments' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'unset_quick_edit', 10, 1 );
    }

}

add_action('admin_init', 'remove_quick_edit');
```

Comment: I would use `admin_init` action hook to check `current_user_can()` (or user roles if needed) and add the `post_row_actions` filter to remove the quick edit.

Comment: That makes sense.  What is the benefit of using `admin_init` here?  Would it forgo extra an extra query on the front end?  Would you like to add an answer or should I edit mine?

Comment: Quick edit doesn't exist on frontend, so an admin action hook is a good event to include this code. Not sure what you mean when talking about the query in the frontend. The benefit of using `admin_init` (or other proper action hook) is that we can be sure that `current_user_can()` function has been defined and we won't get "undefined function" errors, for example like [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14041/current-user-can-on-wordpress-3-1-1) or [this one](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/why-does-calling-current_user_can-crash-wp-292). Edit your answer if you like