# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function file_is_valid_image()

Tags: images, uploads

This is the [function doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/file_is_valid_image/). But when I ran the below I get `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function file_is_valid_image()`

```
    $json_file = get_post_meta( $listing->ID, '_json_file', true );
    $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta( $listing->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true );
    $image_file = get_post_meta( $thumbnail_id, '_wp_attached_file', true );

    //DEBUG
    error_log( "path: " .  $upload_basedir . '/' . $image_file );
    error_log(" path2: " . $upload_basedir . '/' . $json_file );
    
    if ( file_is_valid_image( $upload_basedir . '/' . $image_file ) ) {
        error_log("Image Valid");
    }
```

My file path is like `C:\laragon\www\test/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/placeholder.png`

UPDATE: Ok, I think the error is due to the fact that I fired it [too early](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14041/current-user-can-on-wordpress-3-1-1/14042#14042). But how I slow it down? My `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_setup' );` is already on top of my `functions.php`

And btw, I'm running the code above as WP cron.

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? If not, can you share what was the problem and your solution?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm running the code above as WP cron

The `file_is_valid_image` function is defined in `wp-admin/includes/image.php`, and this file is loaded automatically only on WordPress *admin* pages (in `wp-admin`).

So if you want to use that function on other/non-admin pages, e.g. a page in the site's front-end, a REST API endpoint, or `wp-cron.php` which runs during a [WP-Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) request, you need to **manually load `wp-admin/includes/image.php`**, like so:

```php
// load the file which defines the file_is_valid_image function
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';

// now you can call the function, e.g. in your case:
if ( file_is_valid_image( $upload_basedir . '/' . $image_file ) ) ...
```

But actually, you don't have to use `file_is_valid_image()`, because you can ***easily*** do what it does where it uses `wp_getimagesize()` which is loaded everywhere in WordPress:

```php
// all you need to do is, replace this:
if ( file_is_valid_image( $upload_basedir . '/' . $image_file ) )

// with this:
$size = wp_getimagesize( $upload_basedir . '/' . $image_file );
if ( ! empty( $size ) )
```

#### References

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/file_is_valid_image/#source
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_getimagesize/